# pd.merge and check changed data

Tags: python, pandas, merge

if I have these dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,2,3,4],
                    'col1': ['a','b','c','d'],
                   'col2': ['h','e','l','p']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,2,3,4],
                    'col1': ['a','e','f','d'],
                   'col2': ['h','e','lp','p']})
```

df1

```
   index col1 col2
0      1    a    h
1      2    b    e
2      3    c    l
3      4    d    p
```

df2

```
   index col1 col2
0      1    a    h
1      2    e    e
2      3    f   lp
3      4    d    p
```

I want to merge them and see whether or not the rows are different and get an output like this

```
   index col1  col1_validation col2  col2_validation
0      1    a             True    h             True
1      2    b            False    e             True
2      3    c            False    l            False
3      4    d             True    p             True
```

how can I achieve that?

Comment: What is your merge operation?  Do you want to take `col1` from `df1` and `col2` from `df2` always?  Are these merged on value or index?

Comment: merged on index, comparing df1['col1'] with df2['col1'], and df1['col2'] with df2['col2']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `col1` and `col2` from your "merged" dataframe are just taken from `df1`.  In that case, you can simply compare the `col1`, `col2` between the original data frames and add those as columns:

```
cols = ["col1", "col2"]
val_cols = ["col1_validation", "col2_validation"]

# (optional) new dataframe, so you don't mutate df1 
df = df1.copy()
new_cols = (df1[cols] == df2[cols])
df[val_cols] = new_cols
```

Comment: can I do something like 
`val_cols = cols + '_validation'` without getting an error?

Comment: you could do `val_cols = [c + "_validation" for c in cols]` if you want

Answer (score 1):

You can merge and compare the two data frames with something similar to the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,2,3,4],
                    'col1': ['a','b','c','d'],
                   'col2': ['h','e','l','p']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1,2,3,4],
                    'col1': ['a','e','f','d'],
                   'col2': ['h','e','lp','p']})


# give columns unique name when merging
df1.columns = df1.columns + '_df1'   
df2.columns = df2.columns + '_df2' 

# merge/combine data frames
combined = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)

# add calculated columns
combined['col1_validation'] = combined['col1_df1'] == combined['col1_df2']
combined['col12validation'] = combined['col2_df1'] == combined['col2_df2']
```